# Why isn't X treated as a random variable in linear regression MLE?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, random-variable

I am very confused by this because when I watch videos or read about MLE with linear regression it seems to be commonly assumed that $X$ is fixed or that if it is random we don't care for the purposes of estimating $Y$ using $X\beta$, as $X$ is assumed to be already known.

Assuming I have understood that reasoning properly, why is this so? It's very strange because $X$ seems to be random very commonly in regression scenarios. I've seen a couple threads about this and I don't really understand.

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246047/independent-variable-random-variable), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485011/what-is-a-random-variable-and-what-isnt-in-regression-models) and [here](https://thestatsgeek.com/2013/08/30/why-regression-inference-assuming-fixed-predictors-is-still-valid-for-random-predictors/)

Comment: At the risk of leading you down a rabbit hole, you might want to take a look at ["measurement error"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/255857) or ["error-in-variables"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/225030) models.